# Moderncv: \cvitem text is too large

Tags: fontsize, moderncv

How do I change the text size for items under `\cvitem` to match items under `\cventry` that won't cause problems with other `\moderncvstyle{xyz}`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic} % banking, casual, classic, empty, oldstyle options  
\moderncvcolor{blue}   % black, blue, green, grey, orange, purple, red options  
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry} % default scale=0.7. height= scale * layoutheight
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\section}{\vspace*{.5ex}}{\vspace{.5ex}}{}{}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{R\'esum\'e}     % optional

% the following definition is from the file moderncvstyleclassic.sty
% reformats the \cventry by removing the period at the end of the line
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
%   .\strut% original
    \strut%   remove period
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}

% Fixes spacing if using \cvitem in the classic style by redefining \section. 
\makeatletter   % changes the catcode of @ to 11 aka Make @ symbol a letter
\@ifpackageloaded{moderncvstyleclassic}{%
\let\oldsection\section%
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\leavevmode\unskip\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\oldsection{#1}}}{}
\makeatother % changes the catcode of @ back to 12 aka Make @ symbol an "other"

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Professional Experience}
    \cventry{Year--Year}{Intern}{Financial Services Inc.}{Somewhere}{State}{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item This is something important that I did here. This cventry text is the perfect size.
            \item This is something else equally important that I did here. This cventry text is the perfect size.
        \end{itemize}}

\section{Skills}
    \cvitem[-1.0em]{}{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item These are the skills I have. Why is this cvitem text larger than cventry text?
        \end{itemize}}

\section{Languages}
    \cvitem{}{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item These are the languages I speak. Why is this cvitem text larger than cventry text?
        \end{itemize}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 4 different styles provided by [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv): `casual` (default), `classic`, `oldstyle` and `banking`

- `casual` uses the definition of `\cvitem` as defined in `classic`;
- `classic` uses the following definition for `\cvitem`:

  ```
  \renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
      \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{#3}%
    \end{tabular}%
    \par\addvspace{#1}}
  ```
- `oldstyle` uses the following definition of `\cvitem`:

  ```
  \renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\hintstyle{#2}: }{#3}%
    \par\addvspace{#1}}
  ```
- `banking` uses the definition of `\cvitem` as defined in `\oldstyle`.

You can either redefine `\cvitem`, or use [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch)'s `\xpatchcmd` to patch `#3` and insert `\small`:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch
\xpatchcmd{\cvitem}{#3}{\small #3}{}{}
```

Depending on the style that you use, you may have to adjust the size accordingly. Here's how it would look if you use `classic`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic} % banking, casual, classic, empty, oldstyle options  
\moderncvcolor{blue}   % black, blue, green, grey, orange, purple, red options  
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry} % default scale=0.7. height= scale * layoutheight
\usepackage{etoolbox,xpatch}
\patchcmd{\section}{\vspace*{.5ex}}{\vspace{.5ex}}{}{}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{R\'esum\'e}     % optional

% the following definition is from the file moderncvstyleclassic.sty
% reformats the \cventry by removing the period at the end of the line
\xpatchcmd{\cvitem}{#3}{\small #3}{}{}
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
%   .\strut% original
    \strut%   remove period
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}

% Fixes spacing if using \cvitem in the classic style by redefining \section. 
\makeatletter   % changes the catcode of @ to 11 aka Make @ symbol a letter
\@ifpackageloaded{moderncvstyleclassic}{%
\let\oldsection\section%
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\leavevmode\unskip\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\oldsection{#1}}}{}
\makeatother % changes the catcode of @ back to 12 aka Make @ symbol an "other"

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Professional Experience}
    \cventry{Year--Year}{Intern}{Financial Services Inc.}{Somewhere}{State}{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item This is something important that I did here. This cventry text is the perfect size.
            \item This is something else equally important that I did here. This cventry text is the perfect size.
        \end{itemize}}

\section{Skills}
    \cvitem[-1.0em]{}{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item These are the skills I have. Why is this cvitem text larger than cventry text?
        \end{itemize}}

\section{Languages}
    \cvitem{}{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item These are the languages I speak. Why is this cvitem text larger than cventry text?
        \end{itemize}}
\end{document}
```

<sub>Note that I've removed `\small` from your redefinition of `\cventry` since `\cventry` uses `\cvitem` which now uses `\small` by default (due to the patch).</sub>