# change font size of moderncv

Tags: fontsize, moderncv

How can I increase the font size in `moderncv`?

The font size in `\documentclass` is currently ignored.

I only found solutions to change `\namefont`, `\titlefont`, `\addressfont`, `\quotefont`, `\sectionfont`, `\subsectionfont`, `\hintfont` and `\pagenumberfont`.

But I want to change the standard font size.

Defining my own Mycventry according to [Change body font in moderncv without affecting the other fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49831/change-body-font-in-moderncv-without-affecting-the-other-fonts) is a solution.

However redefining the `\cventry` with `\xpatchcmd` as suggested at [Moderncv: \cvitem text is too large](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159946/95516) does not work.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[22pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\firstname{Font}
\familyname{Size}                                                              

\newcommand\Mycventry[6]{\cventry{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{\Huge#6}}  % this works

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{#6}{\Huge #6}{}{}  % this does not work

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Test Section}
\Mycventry{2012}{Title}{Institute}{City}{}{Mycventry font size working.}
\cventry{2012}{Title}{Institute}{City}{}{cventry font size not working.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this satisfy your needs already? `\documentclass[12pt]{moderncv}`

Comment: related question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49831/change-body-font-in-moderncv-without-affecting-the-other-fonts

Comment: @Benjamin: No. It doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add a MWE and elaborate where the font size should be increased?

Comment: @gman: Yes, defining my own Mycventry works. But how come I cannot redefine the cventry with \xpatchcmd as suggested at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159946/95516 ?

Comment: @FrankBreitling Do you want the "Description" in a bigger font `\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{\small#7}{\Large#7}{}{}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want an oversized CV, you can load the `extsizes` package; `moderncv` only accepts `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage[20pt]{extsizes}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\firstname{Font}
\familyname{Size}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Test Section}

\cventry{2012}{Title}{Institute}{City}{}{cventry font size not working.}

\end{document}
```

The maximum font size provided is 20pt.

[image]